# Visio Stencil for Snowflake?

Tags: visio, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to design architectures that include Snowflake. My tool of preference is Visio; so I'm looking for Snowflake Visio stencils.

My google searches have come up empty, and unfortunately Snowflake was not included in "The official AWS icon set for building architecture diagrams" at https://aws.amazon.com/architecture/icons/.

Has Snowflake released or does Snowflake have plans to release official Snowflake Visio stencils?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a bit of research, but I do not see any plans for official Snowflake Visio stencils at this time. I highly recommend posting this as a new idea on the Snowflake Ideas page and allowing others to vote on it: https://community.snowflake.com/s/ideas